# Are Gilbert Strang's books on calculus and linear algebra suitable for math majors?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, soft-question, education, book-recommendation

I would like to know what are the best resources to use to teach and learn elementary subjects (calculus, linear algebra). I remember when learning calculus, I used Spivak's book, which had wonderful problems, but the explanations were not really memorable, the illustrations weren't that appealing and it didn't have enough applications. I would like to know the mathematician's opinion on Strang's books on calculus and linear algebra and the others. Are they not fit to be recommended to math majors? Are they rigorous on any level? What other books do you recommend that have what these don't?

Also, I think that learning through examples first and some visualisation is superior to putting generalities upfront with countless formulas Therefore if you know any book that's written in this vein, please post it.

P.S. Strang's books stress the importance of matrix notation. Is that good? Does it add any insight?

Comment: Strang's linear algebra books have great intuition and insights.  They are certainly fit to be recommended to math majors, but I think math majors should also read books like Lax's linear algebra book which develop the theory in a more abstract setting and present more rigorous proofs.

Comment: Thanks,any comment on the other books?

Comment: I'm not sure about Strang's book, but I would recommend checking out Apostol's Calculus, Volumes I and II. These volumes are FULL of applications, and have a good beginning outline of linear algebra. The rigor is on the level of Spivak.

Comment: @Darrin I like Apostol a great deal,but it's rather dry and it's unorthodox organization may confuse the crap out of a beginner. It also costs a king's ransom now,sadly.

Comment: I've read apostol's books,it's way  too dry.

Answer (score 10):

I consider both of Strang's books **must-reads** for undergraduates. These are what applied mathematics books **should** look like. There's a perception that applied books are merely rote procedural texts, where proofs are omitted and they basically give toolbox approaches to the material. **Bad** applied books do this—good ones like Strang's don't omit proofs, but they merely downplay them. They are both rich with relevant applications—that is, applications that are currently being used in research and practice by applied mathematicians and other professionals—beautifully written and conceptually careful. The Calculus book has the added bonus of being available online for free at Strang's website. Don't be fooled into spending all your money on the second edition of the calculus book—it's no different from the first, it merely contains Strang's "Highlights of Calculus" in addition, which is good but doesn't really add anything to the book's quality.

A word of warning: There are several versions of Strang's linear algebra texts. The one you really want to read is *Linear Algebra And Its Applications*. The other book-*Introduction To Linear Algebra*-is a dramatically watered down version of this book and it's missing many of Strang's wonderful sidebars and digressions. So the "non-introduction" version is the one you want.

Comment: Thanks,any comments on his applied math book?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that Linear Algebra and its Applications is the better one.  That's the one I have always loved, but I've never read Introduction to Linear Algebra and I wasn't sure how it compared.  I've noticed that Linear Algebra and its Applications is very expensive on amazon, but a pdf can be found online.  Note that Strang has several other excellent books -- Introduction to Applied Math; Computational Science and Engineering; a book on wavelets I haven't read; and a Linear Algebra, Geodesy and GPS book which is great.

Comment: By the way, I just checked and Introduction to Linear Algebra is about 550 pages, whereas Linear Algebra and its Applications is about 460 pages.  I'm not sure what you said about the lengths of the books is correct.

Comment: @littleO I should have clarified my comments. It's not about length per se, it was about the fact that INTRODUCTION doesn't cover anywhere near as many or as deep a selection of topics. It develops topics with more detail and at a lower level then LAWA.

Comment: Are they acceptable for math major though?

Comment: @Daniel Faust Montana ABSOLUTELY as long as they aren't the only textbooks you ever use on the subject. A serious mathematics major will obviously need to supplement them with more theoretical treatments, such as Friedberg,Insel and Spence for linear algebra and Donald Estep,Arthur Mattuck's wonderful- and now affordable!-text or Lax/Terrell for calculus. For the record-while I love the depth and beauty of Spivak, I wonder if the austerity of the text is really appropriate for a beginner,even a very talented one. (continued)

Comment: @Montana cont. So to be honest,I hesitate to recommend it. I know-many here are yelling BLASPHEMY! now at me..........

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 My favorite on rigorous calculus/analysis is Zorich mathematical analysis,what do you think of it(Beautiful applications), too hard  ?

Comment: Do you have anything to say about Lax/Terrell's book?

Comment: @ Montana I like Zorich a great deal, but I think the beginner-even a very good one-is going to find it VERY hard. It also doesn't have anywhere near enough exercises for me. From what I've seen of it,Lax/Terrell looks outstanding-wish it was cheaper.

Comment: @ Mathemagician1234 At what stage should one read Zorich's books?

Comment: @ Mathemagician1234 what the multivariable version of Lax/Terrell's book?

Comment: @Montana The moderators are gonna get pissed at us for carrying on an extended conversation here,so I'm gonna answer these last 2 and then we better move it elsewhere: Zorich's books can be used as intermediate analysis texts, at the level of baby Rudin or Pugh. They can be used by students with some background in rigorous calculus and linear algebra. Sadly,to answer your second question,there really is no multivariable version of Lax/Terrell.There are many wonderful rigorous multivariable calculus books that would make great follow ups-like Hubbard and Hubbard's terrific text.

Comment: @Montana ADDENDUM: I don't know if you're still interested, but I've since found out Lax is class testing a multivariable calculus text as a sequel to Lax/Terrell in Terrell's honors calculus course at Cornell University. I'd love to see a copy of those notes,but we should soon have it officially published. I think once it's available, the 2 books should become the standard choice for an honors calculus course.